I'm trying to write a query that uses a subquery in a left join
I want to find total costs by year for groups of products; and, the I want to exclude historical amounts. I have three tables.
Risks
Risks_RiskID
Risks_Change_Number
Risks_RiskGroup_ID
<other product properties>

Risk_Groups
RiskGroup_ID
<other group properties>

Costs
Costs_RiskID
Costs_Change_Number
Costs_FY
Cost_Risk_Amount

I'm able to get the total costs by Year with this code:
SELECT Risk_Groups.RiskGroup_ID, Costs.Costs_FY, Sum(Costs.Costs_Risk_Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM (Risk_Groups LEFT JOIN 
Risks 
ON Risk_Groups.RiskGroup_ID = Risks.Risks_RiskGroup_ID) 
LEFT JOIN Costs ON (Risks.Risks_Change_Number = Costs.Costs_Change_Number) AND (Risks.Risks_RiskID = Costs.Costs_RiskID)
where Risk_Groups.RiskGroup_ID = 'My test group'
GROUP BY Risk_Groups.RiskGroup_ID, Costs.Costs_FY

and I get
RiskGroupID           Costs_FY     TotalAmount  
My test group         FY 23          0  
My test group         FY 24          100000  
My test group         FY 25          120000

But some risks have multiple versions, and I only want to sum the costs for the most recent versions.
I use this statement to get a view of the most recent change # for each product.
(select r.Risks_RiskID, r.Risks_change_number, r.Risks_RiskGroup_ID
    from risks r
        inner join (
           select risks_Riskid, max(risks_change_number) as maxversion 
           from risks maxr group by risks_riskid) maxr 
           on r.Risks_RiskID = maxr.Risks_RiskID and r.Risks_Change_Number = maxr.MaxVersion)

I'm trying to use this view of the of the latest risk version for each risk in place of the Risks table in my summary query. In the past, I've substituted a subquery for a from table clause in a query. But I want to use my subquery in place of the Risks table. I tried substituting it like this
SELECT Risk_Groups.RiskGroup_ID, Costs.Costs_FY, Sum(Costs.Costs_Risk_Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM (Risk_Groups 
LEFT JOIN 

(select r.Risks_center_rank, r.Risks_RiskID, r.Risks_change_number, r.Risks_RiskGroup_ID 
    from risks r
        inner join (
           select risks_Riskid, max(risks_change_number) as maxversion 
           from risks maxr group by risks_riskid) maxr 
           on r.Risks_RiskID = maxr.Risks_RiskID and r.Risks_Change_Number = maxr.MaxVersion) 

ON Risk_Groups.RiskGroup_ID = r.Risks_RiskGroup_ID) 
LEFT JOIN Costs ON (r.Risks_Change_Number = Costs.Costs_Change_Number) AND (r.Risks_RiskID = Costs.Costs_RiskID)
where Risk_Groups.RiskGroup_ID = 'My test group'
GROUP BY Risk_Groups.RiskGroup_ID, Costs.Costs_FY

but I'm getting an error that I have incorrect syntax near the keyword ON (referring to the first ON statement) And I replaced the tablename Risks with the tablename r, but it looks to me like r is not being recognized as a table.

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question

What DBMS are you using? Always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS.

It is redundant to inclde the table name in every column name. You can always qualify a column with its table name anyway. So, if the column would merely be called change_number, you could still write risks.change_number or costs.change_number.

The subquery (select r.Risks_center_rank ... and r.Risks_Change_Number = maxr.MaxVersion) becomes a virtual table and needs a name. In the illustration below, I have called it 'LatestRisks'
Then other parts of the outer select can only reference the data via that name, not any of the tables involved in the subquery - like you've done for the maxr subquery.
Then the join to Risk_Groups should be Risk_Groups.RiskGroup_ID = LatestRisks.Risks_RiskGroup_ID and the join for costs should be something like ON (LatestRisks.Risks_Change_Number = Costs.Costs_Change_Number) AND (LatestRisks.Risks_RiskID = Costs.Costs_RiskID)
Here is the updated query with layout modified a little to help my understanding of the table relationships.
SELECT Risk_Groups.RiskGroup_ID, Costs.Costs_FY, Sum(Costs.Costs_Risk_Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM 
    (Risk_Groups 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (select     r.Risks_center_rank, r.Risks_RiskID, r.Risks_change_number, r.Risks_RiskGroup_ID 
            from    risks r
                    inner join 
                    (select risks_Riskid, max(risks_change_number) as maxversion 
                        from risks maxr group by risks_riskid
                    ) maxr on r.Risks_RiskID = maxr.Risks_RiskID and r.Risks_Change_Number = maxr.MaxVersion
        ) AS LatestRisks ON Risk_Groups.RiskGroup_ID = LatestRisks.Risks_RiskGroup_ID
    ) 
    LEFT JOIN Costs ON (LatestRisks.Risks_Change_Number = Costs.Costs_Change_Number) AND (LatestRisks.Risks_RiskID = Costs.Costs_RiskID)
where Risk_Groups.RiskGroup_ID = 'My test group'
GROUP BY Risk_Groups.RiskGroup_ID, Costs.Costs_FY


Naming the virtual table and referring to it as LatestRisk worked.

The following is a structure we seldom see:
FROM 
(
  Risk_Groups 
  LEFT JOIN (...) ON ...
) 

we'd rather see
FROM Risk_Groups 
LEFT JOIN (...) ON ...

It is often the case that additional parantheses lessen readability instead of enhancing it.
Moreover, look at the ON clause:
FROM 
(
  Risk_Groups 
  LEFT JOIN (...) ON Risk_Groups.RiskGroup_ID = r.Risks_RiskGroup_ID
) 

The ON clause is supposed to declare how to join the subquery to Risk_Groups. Instead it tells the DBMS how to join r, but r is nowhere to be seen. (You have used r as an alias inside the subquery, but it is not accessable from the outside.)
It often helps to structure a query with a WITH clause aka Common Table Expression = CTE, so as to get step by step to the data.
You haven't tagged your request with your DBMS. Here is an example in standard SQL that works in several DBMS:
WITH
  interesting_risk_groups AS
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM risk_groups
    WHERE riskgroup_id = 'My test group'
  ),
  interesting_risks AS
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM risks
    WHERE risks_riskgroup_id IN (SELECT riskgroup_id FROM interesting_risk_groups)
  ),
  current_risks AS
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM interesting_risks
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY risks_riskid ORDER BY risks_change_number DESC)
    FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
  )
SELECT rg.riskgroup_id, c.costs_fy, SUM(c.costs_risk_amount) AS total_amount
FROM interesting_risk_groups rg
LEFT JOIN current_risks r ON r.risks_riskgroup_id = rg.riskgroup_id
LEFT JOIN costs c ON c.costs_riskid = r.risks_riskid AND c.costs_change_number = r.risks_change_number
GROUP BY rg.riskgroup_id, c.costs_fy
ORDER BY rg.riskgroup_id, c.costs_fy;

